# How to change the structure of tables in multiple data dictionary across a advantage database server?

Tags: python, sql, advantage-database-server

We are having same structure of tables in multiple dictionary on advantage database server version 10. If one change in structure of table in one dictionary we have to change the same in all other data dictionary manually. Is there any way to automate this with any program or tool. The changes can be done across multiple data dictionary in a single process. Please help on this subject.

Comment: There is no built-in functionality in ADS for this, and asking for a *program or tool* is off-topic here. This sounds like an XY problem, though. If you have multiple DDs that contain the same tables with the same structures, it most likely means you're doing something wrong.

Comment: We have multiple DDs for our factories which the table & structures are same. Only name changes. Thank you @Ken White